# .NET Async Get Request - Don't care about Response

Tags: .net, asynchronous, webclient

I want to send a request to a web service and I don't care about the response. The service performs operations in a database--I'm calling it from a simple .NET 4.0 console application that will be set to run on a schedule. This works:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

but blocks the thread until the response is received. I'd rather do:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
```

but this simply doesn't seem to be sending the request (the database operations are not performed). Is there are really simple solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the async version will fail as you're disposing of the client immediately.

You could either not dispose of the client:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

... or (better) attach an event to dispose of it when it completes:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.DownloadStringCompleted += delegate { client.Dispose(); };
client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

(You should check whether you need to subscribe to any other events to dispose of it on failure - I can't remember offhand whether the event is still fired in that case.)

Comment: Ah yes, I have to keep the client alive, don't I? I was trying to make the request, get the server to start doing the work, then disconnect and let the server go on its merry way, but that's not how HTTP works of course...